# Android Studio getting image from folder inside drawable

Tags: java, enums, casting

How to get image from folder located inside drawable

```
RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity);
r.setBackgroundResource(R.???);
```

Image location : 
drawable>imgfolder>image.png

Comment: What does this question have to do with the supposed dupe?

Comment: I suggest you [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html). In short, you want `R.drawable.name_of_resource`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it doesnt help, it is all about file in drawable i need 
to get file which is in folder and that folder is in drawable.

Comment: might be worthwhile to post your activity layout (or the related areas of the RelativeLayout its its rather large) and drawable xml (if the background points to the an xml rather than the graphic)

Comment: @vergnujum please describe the exact folder structure

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it goes like this drawable > images > background.jpg

Comment: I believe you have to place all drawable resources directly in the drawable folder. Then you can use the identifier as I said in my second comment.